# Email class PHP

Tags: php

I'm new to OOP and could use some help.  My class is not working:

```
class Email {

  private $to = 'shummel@...';

  public $subject;
  public $body;

  public function send() {
   $this->addHeader('From: moreinfo@ulsinc.com' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: moreinfo@ulsinc.com' . "\r\n" .
                       'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n");
   $this->addHeader("MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n");
   $this->addHeader("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n");
   $sent = mail($this->to, $this->subject, $this->body, $this->headers);
   return $sent;
  }

  private function addHeader($header) {
   $this->headers .= $header;
  }

 }
```

And here I am calling it:

```
$mail = new Email();
$mail = new Email;
$mail->subject($_POST['subject']);
$mail->body($_POST['body']);
$mail->send();
```

I've done print_r on the $_POST and the values are there.  There are no problems with our mail server.  So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I'd appreciate some help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/), which is a free and mature mailer class for PHP.

Comment: Definitely one of the best - solved a lot of delivery issues by helping to set headers.

Answer (score 3):

$this->headers is not defined. Turn on your error reporting.

Answer (score 1):

and I use `Zend_Mail` , its pretty powerful ,

http://framework.zend.com

btw , you can use it alone : http://epic.codeutopia.net/pack/

http://codeutopia.net/blog/2008/11/14/improved-zend-framework-package-maker/

Answer (score 0):

There is no `subject` and `body` methods. They are attributes.

```
$mail->subject = $_POST['subject'];
$mail->body = $_POST['body'];
```

And of course, never trust data from $_POST -- you need some kind of escaping.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mail = new Email(); 
$mail->subject = $_POST['subject'=; 
$mail->body = $_POST['body']; 
$mail->send();
```

and if you want use the methoted you are useing then try this

```
class Email {   

  private $to = 'shummel@...';   

  public $subject;   
  public $body;   

  public function send() {   
   $this->addHeader('From: moreinfo@ulsinc.com' . "\r\n" .   
           'Reply-To: moreinfo@ulsinc.com' . "\r\n" .   
                       'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n");   
   $this->addHeader("MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n");   
   $this->addHeader("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n");   
   $sent = mail($this->to, $this->subject, $this->body, $this->headers);   
   return $sent;   
  }   

  private function addHeader($header) {   
   $this->headers .= $header;   
  }


  public function SetSubject($subject) {   
   $this->subject = $subject;   
  }

  public function SetBody($body) {   
   $this->body= $body;   
  }

 }

$mail = new Email;    
$mail->SetSubject($_POST['subject']);    
$mail->SetBody($_POST['body']);    
$mail->send();
```

Comment: Thanks, livetolearn.  To the others who posted, I'm trying to learn OOP in doing this.  I know ultimately Zend or phpmailer are more robust choices.